# Has the linux kernel introduced incompatible changes to its "public API"?

Tags: linux-kernel, history, version

I am trying to learn about Semantic Versioning, which states that the major version number should be bumped when an incompatible "public API" change occurs. My thought experiment is to try to understand what the linux kernel numbering would be at, since to my knowledge the major version bumps are arbitrary.

I'm not familiar with Linux internals so bear with me. To my understanding, this "public API" would be the set of C system calls like `sys_write` and `sys_mmap`, and not the [ABI which is used to determine binary compatibility](https://abi-laboratory.pro/?view=timeline&l=linux). From [syscall_64.tbl](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl) this includes about 400 syscalls, some of which are deprecated. Or would the API be everything listed here as [kernel API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/)?

Assuming the syscall definition, has Linux ever introduced backwards-incompatible syscall interface changes? If so, would the major version number be in the hundreds or thousands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s worth mentioning for clarity that the kernel doesn’t follow semantic versioning; as you say the major bumps are arbitrary.

As far as system calls are concerned, there have been incompatible changes, namely removals; [the `syscalls` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) lists obsolete calls which have been removed. This alone would be sufficient to require a non-1.*x* version number if semantic versioning rules were applied.

The kernel API, or rather, what must be preserved in the kernel, is anything that might break a program if it were changed. This covers system call definitions, but also data structures, `/proc` file names and contents, `ioctl` calls, and even system behaviour. It does happen that the kernel API is changed, usually inadvertently, and such changes are usually reverted (so would be handled as missed major bumps followed by fixes in semantic versioning).

Comment: If semver were followed would the major numbers be in the hundreds or thousands? That could prove unwieldy to follow.

Comment: No, there haven’t been all that many intentional backwards-incompatible changes. [Unintentional changes don’t require a major bump if they’re reverted.](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html#what-do-i-do-if-i-accidentally-release-a-backwards-incompatible-change-as-a-minor-version)