# What Version Should Linux Be?

Tags: linux

It's fairly well accepted that Linux doesn't follow semantic versioning and Linus just bumps the major version number every now and then.

I think I read somewhere that the last true major version bump would've been around the v2.5.x mark but I could be wrong there.

Has anyone worked out what version number Linux should have if it followed semantic versioning more closely?

Comment: Why does [it matter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)?

Comment: @roaima - It's interesting from a historical perspective

Comment: I don't see how an alternative present could be construed as history. No matter though; I see someone's answered already.

Comment: @ChrisDavies it makes it easier to identify breaking changes for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unanswerable, because if the kernel *did* follow semantic versioning, it’s possible that breaking changes would be batched to reduce the major bumps required.

The kernel has seen breaking changes since 2.5; system calls are removed every once in a while, as are drivers. See [Has the linux kernel introduced incompatible changes to its "public API"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/716048/86440) for more context.